# Regular Expression for a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I was looking for regular expression to find a string having a particular pattern (first
occurrence )

Consider this as my strings

```
"feat: xyz" 
"chore: jsjs" 
"feature: rpsz" 
// ......
```

I want to do find `feat`, `chore`, `feature` using Regular Expressions. Can someone help me in comprehending the statement for regular expression for the same?

I know the javascript equivalence (without regular expression for the same) for this

```js
const a = "feat: Hello there"

const b = a.split(":") 

const c = b[0]

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a positive look ahead for a colon and take the first element of the match.

```js
var string = "feat: xyz",
    part = string.match(/.*(?=:)/)[0];

console.log(part);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `/^[^:\r\n]+/` that matches any character that is not a colon or linebreak fom the beginning of line.

```js
var test = [
    "feat: xyz" ,
    "chore: jsjs" ,
    "feature: rpsz",
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.match(/^[^:\r\n]+/);
}));
```